# Can I use web-aliases for localhost using Apache?

Tags: apache

My web hotel host (one.com) allows me to define "web-aliases" for my site. I want to use this for multi-language versions of my site. E.g. the alias `fr.example.com` will show a French version of `https://example.com` without changing the showed url. This part is quite straight forward for me...

However... I develop my site locally and use localhost for browsing and testing. I'm not familiar with Apache and all it's configurations. So I wonder if it's possible to create similar web-aliases for localhost, i.e. an alias such as `fr.localhost` ==> `https://localhost`?

Comment: An Apache [alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) is something entirely different. What role does the string `fr.example.com` play here if you want the URL to be `https://example.com` and never change? What criteria should the server use to determine what language to display?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service like [nip.io](https://nip.io), e.g.:

- en.127.0.0.1.nip.io
- fr.127.0.0.1.nip.io

both will point to your localhost.

On most systems, the whole segment 127.0.0.0/8 is mapped to localhost, so you can use things like:

- http://127.0.0.1
- http://127.0.0.2
- http://127.0.0.3

as well. But you will need to explicitly listen on these IPs, though.